# Setup Gstreamer for NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, gstreamer

I have a problem with setting up gstreamer library for my NetBeans IDE. Everytime I try to compile a Gstreamer example code I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library: gstreamer

In this line of code: Gst.init();

I have gstreamer installed on my PC and I have all libraries needed included in my project(jna-4.5.1, gstreamer-java-1.4 and gst1-java-core-0.9.2) Do you have any idea what might be missing?